# pandas performance issue - need help to optimize

Tags: python, pandas

I wrote some python code that makes heavy use of the pandas library. The code seems to be a bit slow, so I ran it through cProfile to see where the bottlenecks are.
One of the the bottlenecks according to the cProfile results is the call to  pandas.lib_scalar_compare:

```
1604  262.301    0.164  262.301    0.164 {pandas.lib.scalar_compare}
```

My question is this - under what circumstances does this get called ? I assume its when I do selecting of part of a DataFrame. 
Here is what my code looks like:

```
if (var=='9999'):
    dataTable=resultTable.ix[(resultTable['col1'] == var1)  
                                             & (resultTable['col2']==var2)].copy() 
else:
    dataTable=resultTable.ix[(resultTable['col1'] == var1)  
                                           & (resultTable['col2']==var2)
                                           & (resultTable['col3']==int(val3))].copy()
```

I have the following questions:

1. Is that the code snippet that eventually calls the code that causes the bottleneck?
2. If so, is there anyway to optimize this?
   The version of pandas I am currently using is **pandas-0.8**.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The `.copy()` doesn't do anything in this case, leaving that off speeds up *slightly*. Presumably this isn't your entire code...

Comment: I'm not sure how big your dataframes are, but you could unstack ResultTable and access it with a multiindex tuple

Answer (score 6):

My code was spending a ton of time in pandas.lib.scalar_compare, and I was able to increase the speed by 10x by converting the datatype of string-based columns to 'category'.

For example:

```
   $ df['ResourceName'] = df['ResourceName'].astype('category')
```

For more information, see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Comment: Thanks, the link is not working, but I manage to reduce my code execution time by 20x!!!

Comment: I think that documentation has moved here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/categorical.html

Answer (score 1):

You could set the index using the columns col1-col3.  Here's a toy example:

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4))

In [2]: df
Out[2]:
    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19

In [3]: df2 = df.set_index(keys=[0,1,2])

In [4]: df2
Out[4]:
           3
0  1  2
0  1  2    3
4  5  6    7
8  9  10  11
12 13 14  15
16 17 18  19
```

**MultiIndex tuple:**

```
In [5]: %timeit df2.ix[(4,5,6)]
10000 loops, best of 3: 99.5 us per loop
```

**Original DataFrame:**

```
In [6]: %timeit df.ix[(df[0]==4) & (df[1]==5) & (df[2]==6)][3]
1000 loops, best of 3: 515 us per loop
```

**UPDATE:** Addressing duplicate indices

```
In [1]: df = DataFrame(np.arange(20).reshape(5,4))

In [2]: df = concat([df, df])

In [3]: df
Out[3]:
    0   1   2   3
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
0   0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6   7
2   8   9  10  11
3  12  13  14  15
4  16  17  18  19
```

This fails:

```
In [4]: df2 = df.set_index(keys=[0,1,2])

In [5]: df2.ix[(0,1,2)]

KeyError: u'no item named 1'
```

This works:

```
In [6]: df2 = df.set_index(keys=[0,1,2]).sort()

In [7]: df2.ix[(0,1,2)]
Out[7]:
       3
0 1 2
0 1 2  3
    2  3
```

Comment: I was a little surprised this was so much faster, but I guess I shouldn't be... :)

Comment: The MultiIndex approach only works as a unique index - if I just wanted to select a bunch of rows that meet a certain criterion I have to use the Boolean approach. Thanks

Comment: If you sort the dataframe this will work.  See my edited response.